# Postgres Update on timestamptz constraint causing duplicates

Tags: postgresql, insert-update

I am running upsert on a table which has a constraint of id and created date. Created date type is timestamptz.

```
insert into target.events (event_id, event_type, created_at, updated_at)
select source.event_id, 'TYPE' event_type, source.created_at::timestamptz as created_at, source.updated_at::timestamptz as updated_at
from
source.capture source
where
source.updated_at between current_date -3 and current_date
on conflict on constraint events_event_id_created_at_key do
update set
updated_at = excluded.updated_at
```

If a record is updated in Source, it introduces a duplicate in target table. I presume this is because of timestamptz column because the created_at has a hour difference (+1 or -1).

How do i make sure that on conflict update works with timestamptz constraint?

```
Source Table : event_id varchar(250), created_at timestamp(3), updated_dt timestamp(3)

Target Table : event_id varchar(250), event_type varchar(100), created_at timestamptz(3), updated_dt timestamptz(3)
```

Source:

```
Event_id : 71b41b2a70cc442496cd7f658a40cf2b20210407
Created_at: 2021-04-07 10:02:30
```

Target:

```
Before Update: 

Event_id : 71b41b2a70cc442496cd7f658a40cf2b20210407
Created_at: 2021-04-07 10:02:30 

After Update:
Event_id : 71b41b2a70cc442496cd7f658a40cf2b20210407
Created_at: 2021-04-07 11:02:30
```

Comment: We need to see the table definitions and sample data that exhibit the problem.

Comment: Updated with data and definitions.

Comment: If the constraints are what they appear to be, that won't happen. But there are still too many things uncertain. Could you come op with a sequence of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that reproduce the problem?

Comment: The issue is with converting the timestamp to timestamptz.  This has a whole host of problems that can't be solved without some independent knowledge of the time zone of the session when the timestamp was created.